# advance search - url encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have very odd problem and I don't know how to get rid of this.

I have one advance search for my project, its basically school search

acc my problem is I am using `LIKE` to compare the option and at the end of the search my query should be like this below:

```
select *
from tbl_schooldetails
where
  state = 'Gujarat'
  and city = 'Ahmedabad'
  and area = 'Navrangpura'
  and ( board = 'xx' or board LIKE '%CBSE Board%' or board LIKE '%Gujarat Board%')
```

but instead I get this below query:

```
select *
from tbl_schooldetails
where
  state = 'Gujarat'
  and city = 'Ahmedabad'
  and area = 'Navrangpura'
  and ( board = 'xx' or board LIKE '�SE Board%' or board LIKE '%Gujarat Board%')
```

If you noticed my `%CB` is converted into " � " sign and so i am not able to search any result related to "CBSE Board" option.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this URL encoding?

this is my code from where this query is generated:

```
  string qry = "select * from tbl_schooldetails where state = '" + sdpd4.SelectedItem.Text + "'";

    if (sdpd2.SelectedItem.Text != "Select City")
    {
        qry += " and city = '" + sdpd2.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    }

    if (sdpd1.SelectedItem.Text != "Select Area")
    {
        qry += " and area = '" + sdpd1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    }

    if (CheckBoxList3.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        qry = qry + " and ( board = 'xx'";

          for (int i = CheckBoxList3.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          {
              if (CheckBoxList3.Items[i].Selected == true)
              {

                  string mt = CheckBoxList3.Items[i].ToString();
                  qry = qry + " or board LIKE '" + '%' + mt + '%' + "'";

              }
          }
            qry = qry + ")";
    }


    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        qry += " and gender ='" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    }



    Response.Redirect("schoolsearchresult2.aspx?search=" + qry);
```

Comment: khyati instead please can you tell me how or from where do you get query

Comment: You aren't passing those parameters right in from a URL are you? How are you actually building and executing these queries? Some additional code would be very helpful - showing how you put your query together and run it against your database would be great. Note that if you are passing parameters straight through from a URL you are at serious risk of SQL Injection.

Comment: Did you try anything? Like URLDecode()?
And as it was mentioned earlier it is not a good idea to pass complete query or query parameters via URL.

Comment: no i didnt use URLDecode() ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited** now that the original question is clearer.

Just change this:

```
Response.Redirect("schoolsearchresult2.aspx?search=" + qry);
```

To this:

```
Response.Redirect("schoolsearchresult2.aspx?search=" 
    + HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(qry));
```

**...but:** my warning (and everybody else's) remains correct: passing a WHERE clause in your query string is *very dangerous*--trivial tweaking of the resulting URL can ***destroy your database.***

**Original answer**

You seem to be putting %CB into a URL, which is interpreted on the server as a hex digit.

If you use %25CB it should be interpreted as "%CB".

Alternatively you could use one of the built-in c# functions. I think the one you need is [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx).

**VERY IMPORTANT:**

If this is a real application, not a proof-of-concept project, [you **must not** copy data directly from the URL into your SQL string!](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: sry to mark as ans after soooo long, but i acc solved it today. . . hahaha. i was looking for some other options but thought this ws d best . . . thanks a lot

Comment: for anyone having this weird problem, i just used Server.UrlEncode(qry) to pass the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you build your sql query this way so you dont have to worry about the url encoding and Sql Injection

```
string sqlQuery = "select *
from tbl_schooldetails
where
  state = @state
  and city = @city
  and area = @area
  and ( board = @board1 or board LIKE ";
 sqlQuery += "%@board2%";
sqlQuery += " or board LIKE %@board3%");
```

and then when execute the query use

e.g.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", Request.Form["state"]);
```

...... and so on

Comment: It's good to give him the details, but...why are you using `String.Format` to concatenate constants?

Comment: ya thx a lot for the solution but i already did the coding in most of the project and its working 100% fine for all the options. so i am not thinking of changing the coding for now. just need any solution related url encoding.